# Invoking javascript in iframe from parent page, IE issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

This is a follow up to this question: [Invoking javascript in iframe from parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page)

I've implemented the answer provided by @Tomalak.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taa1953/aNsqB/)

The problem is this, the content in the `iframe` is dynamically created (so no cross domain issues). Within the content is a button whose `onclick` event handler calls `window.print()`. This prints only the content of the `iframe`(which is good and is serving as proof of concept).

Additionally, there is a button on the parent page which calls a public function published by the `iframe`. The function is `printContent`, and like the `iframe` button's `onclick` event handler, it also calls `window.print()`.

This is the issue, when printing from the button on the parent page using IE 8, the content of the parent page also prints. (This does not happen with Chrome.)

Is there a fix which makes IE 8 print only the content of the `iframe`?

Interestingly enough, returning `window.document.title` via a public function, does return the `title` of the `iframe` content, even when using IE 8.

The fiddle demonstrates the problem and offers more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE you need to set focus to the window you want to print. This prints iframe when function is in parent page:

```
function printContent(){
    var el = document.getElementById('myFrame');
    el.contentWindow.focus();
    el.contentWindow.print();
    return;
}
```

If function is in the iframe, you can print it from anywhere:

```
function printContent(){
    window.focus();
    window.print();
    return;
}
```